# How to run flash inside tor browser with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, flash, tor

I am full-warned about the security issues. My question is not about that, please don't answer about it.

I have to browse some website using Tor with Flash enabled, but Tor Browser Kit came with flash disabled by default. Can someone point me how to install and run Flash web sites inside Tor Browser Bundle?

Any solution for same problem with Windows 7 is full aprecciated too, btw.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- uninstall or delete the tor browser file.
- Then go and download another tor browser file from www.torproject.com.
- Then extract it and enter into the tor browser.

Now try playing a flash video.

If it fails to play, go to **Tools** > **Add Ons** > **Plugins** and hopefully you will see "***Shockwave Flash 1......***" just enable it and ENJOY!!

Answer (score 6):

Tools -> Addons -> Plugins

Flash Player should be there, but disabled...
You have just to enable it.

Comment: its not there. add on plugins is empty

Comment: You have the newest version of TOR?

Comment: yes, just downloaded. @Marqin

Comment: Have you installed flash package?

Answer (score 3):

Flash is blocked by default in 'Tor browser' bundle. What you have to do is click on **Noscript** --> **Options** -->**Embeddings**. Unchecked *Forbid/Video*,*Forbid Adobe flash* and *Forbid Other plugins*.In **External Filter** add the site you want to watch the videos from. At your browser go to **Add-ons** and enable *Shockwave Flash*(you have to continue doing that each time you open a new browser).But you do this at your own risk of loosing your anonymous browsing.

Comment: nice. gonna try soon to lose my anonymous identity. =D Thanks.